# Why can't I check this checkbox? (CodeIgniter/jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a user interface with a list of product images and checkboxes next to each image to 'veto' the product. Suddenly today the checkboxes stopped working, they can't be checked. They were working fine a week ago and no changes have been made to the site recently.

The site was built using CodeIgniter 3.1.2, jQuery UI, Bootstrap and PHP version 7.1.33. A sample of the checkbox code is below. Since everything was working fine last week and no changes have been made recently I have to assume that something it was relying on became unsupported, but I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Do you see any red flags in the below code that might cause a checkbox to stop working?

```
<div class="item">
                     <div class="item__header">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                             <input class="largerCheckbox"  type="checkbox" id="previewVeto"
                                 disabled                                      onclick="veto('')">
                           <span class="checkbox__text-checked">Package Vetoed</span>
                           <span class="checkbox__text-regular">Veto this Package</span>
                           <span class="checkbox__view">
                              <svg class="svg-icon-ok"> <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-icon-ok"></use></svg>
                           </span>
                        </label>
                     </div><!-- item__header -->
                     <div class="item__image">
                        <img src=https://i.etsystatic.com/12743396/r/il/b2ae42/2900536844/il_fullxfull.2900536844_jx1j.jpg alt="">
                     </div><!-- item__image -->
                     <div class="item__info">
                        <h3 class="item__title"> </h3>
                        <p class="item__person">CUSTOMER NAME</p>
                     </div><!-- item_info -->
                  </div><!-- item -->
               </div><!-- col-12 -->
                              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="item__header">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                             <input class="largerCheckbox"  type="checkbox" id="previewVeto"
                                 disabled                                      onclick="veto('')">
                           <span class="checkbox__text-checked">Package Vetoed</span>
                           <span class="checkbox__text-regular">Veto this Package</span>
                           <span class="checkbox__view">
                              <svg class="svg-icon-ok"> <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-icon-ok"></use></svg>
                           </span>
                        </label>
                     </div><!-- item__header -->
                     <div class="item__image">
                        <img src=https://i.etsystatic.com/6792430/r/il/be915c/2355877777/il_fullxfull.2355877777_4x72.jpg alt="">
                     </div><!-- item__image -->
                     <div class="item__info">
                        <h3 class="item__title"> </h3>
                        <p class="item__person">CUSTOMER NAME</p>
                     </div><!-- item_info -->
                  </div><!-- item -->
               </div><!-- col-12 -->
                              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                  <div class="item">
                     <div class="item__header">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                             <input class="largerCheckbox"  type="checkbox" id="previewVeto"
                                 disabled                                      onclick="veto('')">
                           <span class="checkbox__text-checked">Package Vetoed</span>
                           <span class="checkbox__text-regular">Veto this Package</span>
                           <span class="checkbox__view">
                              <svg class="svg-icon-ok"> <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#svg-icon-ok"></use></svg>
                           </span>
                        </label>
                     </div><!-- item__header -->
                     <div class="item__image">
                        <img src=https://i.etsystatic.com/17379511/r/il/ecc770/1845923487/il_fullxfull.1845923487_j02p.jpg alt="">
                     </div><!-- item__image -->
                     <div class="item__info">
                        <h3 class="item__title"> </h3>
                        <p class="item__person">CUSTOMER NAME</p>
                     </div>
```

This is the javascript called by the page...

```
//run when document is loaded
//uses jquery syntax
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#cssmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

  $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   
    
    
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
      checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
    
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    
    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;  
    }       
  });

});

//run when mobile-menu-toggle is clicked to show menu
$('.mobile-menu-toggle').click(function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('shown');
});

var href = "#positive";
var touched = false;

$('.switcher').click(function(event) {
  console.log(touched);
  event.preventDefault();
  var href_prev = href;
  href = $(event.target).attr('href');

  if(href_prev != href){
    jQuery(href_prev).addClass('hidden');
    jQuery(href).removeClass('hidden');
  }

  if(href === '#negative'){
    $(this).addClass('negative');
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass('negative');
  }

  var value = jQuery('.switcher').hasClass('negative') ? 'N' :  'P';
  jQuery('.keyword-form [name="type"]').val(value);
});



$('.switcher').on('touchend', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('negative');

  var href_prev = href;

  href = href == '#negative' ? '#positive' :  '#negative';

  if(href_prev != href){
    jQuery(href_prev).addClass('hidden');
    jQuery(href).removeClass('hidden');
  }

  var value = jQuery('.switcher').hasClass('negative') ? 'N' :  'P';
  jQuery('.keyword-form [name="type"]').val(value);

});


$(".collapse-trigger").click(function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded').siblings('.collapse-target').slideToggle();
});

$("[name^=country]").on('change', function(){
  var checked = $(this).closest('.item-preview').find(':checked');
  $(this).closest('.item-preview').siblings('.section-comment').find('.val').text(checked.length);
});


//run when element with id [name=color] is clicked
$("[name^=color]").on('change', function(){
  var checked = $(this).closest('.item-preview').find(':checked');
  var text = [];
  checked.each(function(index, el) {
    text.push($(el).data('name'));
  });
  $(this).closest('.item-preview').siblings('.section-comment').text(text.join(', ') );
});


$('.keyword-edit .keyword').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var keywords = $(this).closest('.item-preview ').find('.keyword');
  $(this).closest('.item-preview').siblings('.section-comment').find('.val').text(keywords.length - 1 ) ;
  $(this).remove();

});
var Cookie =
{
   set: function(name, value, days)
   {
      var domain, domainParts, date, expires, host;

      if (days)
      {
         date = new Date();
         date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
         expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
      }
      else
      {
         expires = "";
      }

      host = location.host;
      if (host.split('.').length === 1)
      {
         // no "." in a domain - it's localhost or something similar
         document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
      }
      else
      {
         // Remember the cookie on all subdomains.
          //
         // Start with trying to set cookie to the top domain.
         // (example: if user is on foo.com, try to set
         //  cookie to domain ".com")
         //
         // If the cookie will not be set, it means ".com"
         // is a top level domain and we need to
         // set the cookie to ".foo.com"
         domainParts = host.split('.');
         domainParts.shift();
         domain = '.'+domainParts.join('.');

         document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain="+domain;

         // check if cookie was successfuly set to the given domain
         // (otherwise it was a Top-Level Domain)
         if (Cookie.get(name) == null || Cookie.get(name) != value)
         {
            // append "." to current domain
            domain = '.'+host;
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain="+domain;
         }
      }
   },

   get: function(name)
   {
      var nameEQ = name + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i=0; i < ca.length; i++)
      {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0)==' ')
         {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
         }

         if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
      }
      return null;
   },

   erase: function(name)
   {
      Cookie.set(name, '', -1);
   }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( function() {

  var value = parseInt($( ".slide-hungry .inner").data('value'));

    $( ".slide-hungry .inner").slider({
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
      step: 1,
      range: true,
      values: [0, value],

      slide: function( event, ui ) {
       switch (ui.values[ 1 ] ){
        case 0:
          jQuery('.slide-target').text('Not Hugry');
          break;
        case 1:
          jQuery('.slide-target').text('A Bit Hugry');
          break;
        case 2:
         jQuery('.slide-target').text('Very Hugry');
          break;
        case 3:
         jQuery('.slide-target').text('Very Very Hugry');
          break;
        case 4:
         jQuery('.slide-target').text('Duying of Huger');
          break;
        case 5:
         jQuery('.slide-target').text('ARGH!!!');
          break;
       }
      }
    });
  } );
})
```

Comment: Has any errors in browser's console?

Comment: Look for that `disabled` attributes in checkboxes: `<input class="largerCheckbox"  type="checkbox" id="previewVeto"
                                 disabled                                      onclick="veto('')">` and remove them

Comment: is this on a shared server? does it still work on your local machine? has the php version changed? enable ERROR REPORTING in the main CI index file and see if you get any hints spit in your browser's console and network tab.